# Pasar de JFrame cada ciertos segundos, como lo puedo hacer teniendo en cuenta que el JFrame se llama Menu?

Tags: java, java-swing

//Este es lo que intento pero no se en que parte de el codigo puedo poner el codigo para pasar de JFrame, me podrian decir porfavor

```
public static void pasar(){
        try {

       Thread.sleep(1000);

         } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
         }
    }
```

Comment: después del sleep :)

Comment: No me deja poner el dispose(); porque me dice que es un metodo estatico

Comment: pásale como parámetro tu instancia de frame en la que estás y al que quieres ir y debe funcionar

Comment: Perdon, me dice que un metodo no estatico no puede ser referenciado en un contexto estatico, y pasandole como parametros lo que me dijistes, me dice que se requieren argumentos

Comment: así es, pero un método estático si puede ser referenciado, por ello mándale de parámetros tus instancias de frames, así oprará como una función pura